# Cannot import MetaTrader5

Tags: python, numpy, importerror, metatrader5

While importing MetaTrader5 :

```py
import MetaTrader5 as mt
```

I got the following error :

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xe

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\OneDrive\Documents\Programmation\Projets\TRAI\utilities_mt5.py:10
    import MetaTrader5 as mt

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MetaTrader5\__init__.py:257
    from ._core import *

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I've search a lot and found nothing, so I'm asking, hoping for some answers.

I'm using Spyder, Python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your numpy

```
pip install -U numpy
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It doesn't work, same error input

Comment: Then I don't know what might be the problem. I've seen some answers on the internet that you may need a specific version of numpy to overcome this error